# Streamlit app going to sleep due to less traffic

Tags: streamlit

I have streamlit app deployed on streamlit cloud I got email that app hasn't seen traffic in the past days, so it will go to sleep, visitors will need to wake the app, which can take a minute or two. So is there any way to keep the app alive?

Do I need to write scripts to maintain traffic in the streamlit app.

Comment: Just leave it that way. It helps the host in any way. Waking a sleeping app is not an issue. An interested user is going to open the app anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to keep Streamlit apps awake at all times if they're hosted on Streamlit Community Cloud. If you need the app to be awake at all times regardless of traffic, I'd recommend looking into [paid hosting options](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099).

Answer (score 0):

Set a cron job to run that opens up the site every day?

As of 2023, I don't even get an email saying it's going to sleep. I just looked at it today and found out it was.

A bit annoying... but they are also offering free unlimited hosting for public apps. So, I understand why they do it!

Answer (score 0):

Once in 7 days you have to push a commit to the app repo to keep it awake... Its just that simple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).